# C# Number of deleted rows in DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable, rows

I have a Datatable from which I have removed several rows via

```
bindTable.Rows[index].Delete();
```

At a later stage I would like to know how many rows I have deleted that way. I know that I can loop through the bindTable.Rows and count the rows in the deleted state, but is there a more direct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

No, but another way of doing it can be the [DataTable.RowDeleted Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rowdeleted)

```
int rowDeletedCount = 0; 
...
bindTable.RowDeleted += (o, e) => rowDeletedCount++;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the most practical way is also your answer or count the number of delete iterations from your sample code.

private int deletedRowCount;

bindTable.Rows[index].Delete();

deletedRowCount++;

Regards,